# Spring recommendations: proxying mechanism vs @Transactional on class or interface

Tags: java, spring, transactions, aop, spring-aop

Spring doc has the two recommendations:

> Spring recommends that you only annotate concrete classes (and methods
>   of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to
>   annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional
>   annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but this works
>   only as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based
>   proxies. The fact that Java annotations are not inherited from
>   interfaces means that if you are using class-based proxies
>   (proxy-target-class="true") or the weaving-based aspect
>   (mode="aspectj"), then the transaction settings are not recognized by
>   the proxying and weaving infrastructure, and the object will not be
>   wrapped in a transactional proxy, which would be decidedly bad.

(from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html)

and

> Spring AOP uses either JDK dynamic proxies or CGLIB to create the
>   proxy for a given target object. (JDK dynamic proxies are preferred
>   whenever you have a choice).

(from http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)

Do I understand correctly that in order to follow both recommendations, I need to have `@Transactional` annotation on concrete class, but still provide an interfaces (that this class implements) containing all transactional methods, so that Spring can use JDK dynamix proxies for this interface?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: BTW: I recommend to use Compile Time AspectJ, then the Aspects get taken in accout even if you invoke a method from inside the same bean (`this.otherMethod()`).

Answer (score 2):

It works like this

1. Have a business interface with methods, do not annotate interface methods with `@Transactional`
2. Write an implementation class for interface defined above and annotate methods in impl class with `@Transactional`

As spring recommends usage of JDK dynamic proxies which are interface based hence we need to have business interface in place.
Also, as stated

> Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces

We need to annotate concrete / implementation class methods with `@Transactional`